# Почему PipedInputStream не возвращает -1 хотя в документации написано?

Tags: java, io

Здравствуйте, такая проблема что цикл который должен закончиться когда метод у объекта `PipedInputStream` вернет `-1`, а он не возвращает. Как быть? Где я ошибся? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
public void rw1() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out)
    ) {
        out.write("message".getBytes("UTF8"));
        out.flush();
        int data = in.read();
        while ((data) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) data);
            System.out.println(data);
            data = in.read();
        }
        System.out.println(new String(sb));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Поток выполнения просто останавливается и дальше не идет.

Я так понимаю, что он ждет еще данных, можно было бы воспользоваться методом `available()`, но мне все таки хочется понять логику с этой -1 которую `read()` должен вернуть. В чем тут дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [PipedInputStream.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html#read()) блокирующий согласно документации:

> Reads the next byte of data from this piped input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. **This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.**

Т.е. метод блокирует исполнение до наступления одного из следующих событий:

- появятся доступные для чтения данные, тогда метод вернет прочитанный байт;
- заканчивается входной поток (в Вашем случае это произойдет если закроется `out`), тогда метод вернет -1;
- произойдет исключение.

Т.к. `out` не закрывается, то и -1 не вернется никогда. Поток будет ожидать следующих данных.

> Я так понимаю, что он ждет еще данных, можно было бы воспользоваться методом `available()`...

В принципе все правильно понимаете и да, в данном случае можно использовать неблокирующее чтение (`available()`).